# Query processing time for network table creation using pgRouting 1.05

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting, route, catchment-area

I am trying to follow [these](http://anitagraser.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/) steps for creation of a network table using pgRouting 1.05.

In my case I have two road geometry tables, one is bangalore_road and the other is all_india_roads. Obviously the bangalore_road table is a subset of big all_india_roads. So when I run the network query (after creating ext_view and node table) on bangalore_road_network it took almost around 3 hours to finish it up. In this case the size of my bangalore_roads table is around 8MB.

Now, when I run the same procedure on my all_india_road table (size ~280 MB) it seems like the query is just going on and on. i.e. now it's almost a week i.e 6 days and this query is still running at-least that's what I can see in the pgAdmin.

So just wonder if anyone have previously gone through the same blog post with huge dataset/tables and if yes then is there any way to speedup this process?

Like, running the query part by part (North_India, West_India, East_India, South_India etc.) on several machines and then combining all network tables together at end.`not sure though as start_id and end_id may collide.`

My system configs are:

```
PostgreSQL: 8.4
Processor: Intel Xeon @3.10 GHz
RAM: 4GB
OS: 64 bit win 7.
```

Comment: Is there a reason you chose to use an antiquated version of pgRouting and a no longer supported version of PostgreSQL on a newish version of Windows? Current versions of windows PostGIS come packaged with pgRouting 2.0 (and also support 64-bit PostgreSQL)

Comment: Actually the environment I'm working is a pre-configured, also the other folks working with me are are using the same setup and they have there own postgis functions/algorithms in it. So practically can't update the system.